# how do you parse this date in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I want to ask if how do you parse this date to look like : "12/24/1990" using Carbon in laravel or built in php date methods

```
$user->profile->birthdate
```

Comment: You say parse but the wording sounds like you want to know how to format a date. `echo $user->profile->birthdate->format('m/d/Y');` should do it.

Comment: Broadly speaking this is a rather simple task that both carbon and the PHP manual seem to document well e.g. [`createFromFormat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) (since carbon extends the native DateTime class, it also has this method). Is this just a matter of how to use this function or is there more to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
Carbon::parse($user->profile->birthdate)->format('m/d/Y')
```

Comment: I want to pass it as a prop like this :) 
```html
<edit-criminal :birthdate="{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($criminal->profile->birthdate)->format("m/d/Y") }}"
```
> But unfortunately it doesn't pass as a  date but instead it divides it like `12/31/1990`

Answer (score 2):

You may use [date mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) like this in your `Profile` model (or [date casting](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting) as @Jesper said):

```
class Profile extends Model
{
    protected $dates = [
        'birthdate', // date fields that should be Carbon instance
    ];
}
```

So, whenever you retrieve the model, `Laravel` will automatically cast the `birthdate` property to `Carbon` instance and you can use the `format` method to format it, for example:

```
$user->profile->birthdate->format('m/d/y');
```

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions works for both Laravel 5.* and 6.*

**First Solution**

You can cast your `birthdate` variable to always be in the format you want, by putting the following in your `Profile` model.

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'birthdate' => 'datetime:m/d/Y',
];
```

Reference:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting

**Second solution:**

You can also cast the `birthdate` to always be a `Carbon` object in your `Profile` model, which you can then later format as you want, using the following code:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = [
    'birthdate',
];
```

And then you can always do the following to format it in different ways:

```
$user->profile->birthdate->format('m/d/Y')
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Answer (score 0):

Using laravel Carbon, you can parse date like below

```
        $carbonToday = Carbon::now();
        $date = $carbonToday->format('m/d/Y');
```

Using PHP method

```
       $carbonToday = Carbon::now();
       $date = date('m/d/Y',strtotime($carbonToday));
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

using Laravel carbon method

```
$date = "12-24-1990";
$carbon_date = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $date);
```

using PHP method

```
 $newdate = date('m/d/Y',strtotime($date));
```

Comment: The separation symbol could not be found Unexpected data found. Trailing data (View:

Comment: ```<edit-user :birthdate="{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $user->profile->birthdate) }}" :admins="{{ $admins }}" :countries="{{ $countries }}" :criminal="{{ $user}}">
</edit-user>
```

Comment: This is not correct, as you're trying to create the `Carbon` object from the `$date` of format `m-d-Y`, but the format you're telling Carbon it should read the date as is `m/d/Y`

Comment: $newdate = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $user->profile->birthdate);
<edit-user :birthdate="{{ $newdate }}" :admins="{{ $admins }}" :countries="{{ $countries }}" :criminal="{{ $user}}"> </edit-user>

Comment: @Jesper where I am trying to do that. this is how I used it in laravel and it is working fine

Comment: The date in the table isn't by default in the format he would like, but you're trying to create the `Carbon` object from the output he's actually searching for

Comment: we can just suppose that this might be the fromat from which he is trying to create new format